# Clamping problems with diagonal camera rotation around object based on mouse input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, physics

I'm working on a script which rotates the camera diagonally (3D x & 3D y axis) around an player object. Inputs are following:

- mouse z-axis for the y-axis rotation around the object
- mouse x-axis for the diagonal  "over-the-shoulder" rotation, thus modifying both y and x of camera rotation:

[demo of my current camera script](https://youtu.be/yRvaTT7uwA8)

It works, however, I can't get to clamp the y-axis rotation for the camera. X-axis works as wished. Watch the video above to see the problem at the end. It overrotates on the y axis so that the camera faces the player in the complete wrong direction. Maybe someone with a functioning brain can come up with a solution? Would be awesome as hell, thanks in advance!

Here's my script:

```
void Update() {
        mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        mouseY = -(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime);

        rotationXAxis += mouseY;
        rotationXAxis = ClampAngle(rotationXAxis, -30f, 30f);

        float rotationYAxis = rotationXAxis;
        rotationYAxis = ClampAngle(rotationYAxis, 0f, 30f);

        Quaternion fromRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationXAxis, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y - rotationYAxis * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        Quaternion rotation = toRotation;

        Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(xPosOffset, yPosOffset, -distance);
        Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + player.position;

        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;

        player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
        mouseY = Mathf.Lerp(mouseY, 0, Time.deltaTime);
    }

    float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max) {
        if (angle < -360F)
            angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F)
            angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
```

Comment: Biggest problem for me is that you dont have or use original position. 
Because you will be able to calculate some rotation and just added to original position.

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain you in pseudo.

Sinus and cosinus are basicaly same but are offset by 90degrees.

What this function are producing is -1 .. 1 number what is -100% .. 100%

basicaly what you need is

```
var _x,_y,_z; //original position
var deg; // 0..360
x = _x * sin(deg);
y = _y * cos(deg);
z = _z;
```

This was rotate around world [0,0,0]

If you want to rotate around another axis

```
var a_x,a_y,a_z;

x = _x + a_x * sin(deg);
y = _y + a_y * cos(deg);
z = _z + a_z;
```

Biggest key is to preserve default location [_x,_y,_z]
Do not do this mistake

```
x = x * sin(deg);
```

Precisely it is a matrix

```
   _x   _y  _z
x [cos -sin  0]
y [sin  cos  0]
z [0      0  1]

x = _x * cos(deg) + _y * -sin(deg) + _z * 0;
y = _x * sin(deg) + _y * cos(deg)  + _z * 0;
z = _x * 0        + _y * 0         + _z * 1;
```

Look at 3d matrix for your axis.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Try some thing like this

```
void Update(Player player) {
    _position = player.position;

    mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    mouseY = -(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime);

    _delta_x = mouseX - _position.x;
    _delta_y = mouseY - _position.y;
    _delta_z = 0;

    _rot_x = ClampAngle(mouseX, mouseY, -30f, 30f);         
    _rot_y = ClampAngle(mouseX, mouseY, -30f, 30f);
    _rot_z = 0;

    Vector3 position = new Vector3(_delta_x, _delta_y, _delta_z);
    position = position.rotate (rot_x, rot_y, rot_z);
    position = position.add(_position.x,_position.y,_position.z);

    player.position = position;
}
```